# Node - look up the value of an arbitrary variable

Tags: node.js

Take this code for an example:

```
(() => {
    const data = []
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws:/localhost:5555');
    ws.onmessage = (frame) => data.push(frame.data);
})();
```

Is it possible to look up the value of `data` without stopping the application, or breakpointing `onmessage` and waiting for it to occur? Is it possible to *just* look up the value of any variable that I know to be stored persistently somewhere?

Comment: YES, as long as you're in the correct scope. Why are you wrapping it in an IIFE? If you need to use the IIFE you could pass it an argument that you mutate or set a value in declared variables in a containing scope.

Comment: IIFE is for executing the function right after its declaration here (no need to call it explicitly)

Comment: There is no persistent object in RAM in the code above. `data` will be garbage collected immediately after the IIFE is called (well, not necessarily immediately but could be immediately, what I'm trying to say is `data` is temporary in this code)

Comment: @slebetman - That's not necessarily true because `ws.onmessage` is still live, long after the IIFE runs and it references `data`.  So, there are still live references so as long as those references stay active, `data` will not be GCed.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah. Don't know how I missed that. In which case there is no way to do it for the code above and there should not be a way to do it otherwise it would break scope protection provided by the closure (yes, I know that you can debug the interpreter and find it at the C level but it should not be possible at the js level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables inside a function are private to within that function scope.  Only code inside that function scope can examine them.

If you're in the debugger, you will need to be at a breakpoint inside that function scope in order to see that variable.

Sometimes it's appropriate to move the declaration of a variable to a higher scope so that after it is modified inside some local scope, it's value will persist and can be accessed from a higher scope.  I don't know what real problem you're trying to solve here to know whether that makes sense for your situation or not.

More likely, since variables like your `data` variable get modified at some unknown time, the only way some outside code can know when to look at an updated value is by participating in some sort of event system or callback system that notifies outside that it now has a new value.  In that case, it's common to just pass the new value to the callback or along with the event.  Then the outside code gets the value that way, rather than having to declare it in some parent scope.